# Constructions like　[ "direct speech" と noun ]

Tags: grammar

The next sentence sounds enough strange for me, as I have got used to constructions like "「...」と（Aさんが）言った。" or something similar.  But, here it looks like at least the word "言う" was omitted.

Why do we have just "**と**運転手" after the direct speech?

> 「ああ、あの道ですね。ヒルキンに、よく通りましたよ」**と**運転手。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a pure omission. Omitting は言った at the end of a sentence is fairly common in novels.

It makes the sentence sound light to make the whole paragraph flow smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

A common feature in Japanese is to shorten things down to its very essence, in this case が言いました/が言った are simply omitted because to a native speaker it is obvious what the verb should be.

Comment: It appears it was obvious even to OP.